# How to get non-dynamic symbols in GCC backtrace?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

GCC's `backtrace_symbols()` only resolves dynamic symbols, since handling all types of symbols is [something GCC maintainers do not want to get into](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=169017).

How would I go about extracting non-dynamic symbols obtained from GCC's `backtrace()` function myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what `addr2line` does using bfd. That is one approach I have used successfully.
More specifically, [backtracefilt](http://www.plunk.org/~hatch/goodies/backtracefilt.C) gets you basically all the way there, you just need to adapt it to take the addresses from backtrace instead of parsing a file.

Answer (score 1):

`libdw`, part of [elfutils](https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/), can be used to read the DWARF debugging information that is present if you compiled with `-g`.